# Calculate the throughput of a processor in bits per second

Tags: cpu, throughput

Let's say for example you have an 64-bit 3.2 GHz processor with 8 MB of Cache. What is the theoretical and practical throughput as it would write to RAM (assuming there are no RAM bottlenecks)?

Thank you!

Comment: *"assuming there are no RAM bottlenecks"* -- That is not a practical or reasonable assumption.  The very fact that there is processor cache implies that the RAM cannot keep up with memory requests.

Answer (score 0):

For the theoretical bandwidth, that is not a number you can calculate, it is part of the specifications of the processor. For example looking at the specification page for a [Intel® Core™ i7-4980HQ Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/83503/Intel-Core-i7-4980HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-4_00-GHz) under `Memory Specification` you can see it states the max bandwidth is 25.6 GB/s.

As for practical throughput, you would have to look at the RAM bottlenecks and see what the throughput of the ram you are using is.

Comment: I disagree, pls read my answer.